# Correct way of using JINJA template for title in flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to use jinja for setting default title for page for that I am using

```
Home{% block title %}

    {% endblock title %}</title>
```

now on some other page I need to use this block so there if I am using only **-About** is shown on the title

```
{% block title %}
    -About
        {% endblock title %}</title>
```

***expected is Home-About***

if I use blockextend whole home page is coming on about page which I don't way how can I correct
this

```
 {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block title %}
        About
            {% endblock title %}</title>
```

Comment: if `Home` shouldn't be in all titles then don't set it as default but remove `Home` from main template and later use `Home-About` instead of `-About`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do the title is have something like this in your base.html file

```
{% if title %}
     <title>Home - {{title}}</title>
{%else%}
    <title>Home</title>
{%endif%}
```

And then for each of your routes when you render the template you can set a title, if no title is set then the title will just be Home.

For example

```
retrun render_template("about.html", title = "About")
```

Would give you the title "Home - About"

If you want to use your method of doing it, I think what you have done should work, but in the base.html file you can change `{% endblock title %}` to just
`{%endblock%}`, and do the same in the other html file. Maybe that will solve your issue?

I hope that helps, sorry if I have misunderstood what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, it is better to use jinja macros. here is how:

my_macros.html

```
{% macro render_title(arg1, arg2) %}

     # write your jinja html here

{% endmacro%}

{% macro render_something(arg1, arg2) %}

     # write your jinja html here

{% endmacro%}
```

Then in your html where you want to use the macro:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% from 'my_macros.html' import render_title %}
{% block content %}

    {{ render_title("something", "something else") }}

    # jinja html anywhere

{% endblock content %}
```